# Pause (verb) in 5 minutes or Pause (verb) for 5 minutes

Tags: prepositions

Which one is correct? "Pause in 5 minutes" or "Pause for 5 minutes". I want to use PAUSE as a verb to tell somebody to stop his presentation in order for the listeners to have 5 minutes for discussion. Thank you.

Comment: So you want the presenter to pause for 5 minutes of discussion?

Comment: @Hot Licks: I think she wants the presenter to pause so that they can discuss the matter presented till that time.

Comment: Thank you Hot Licks and Ram Pillai. Yes, I want the presenter to pause so that we can discuss for a period of 5 minutes. And I wonder whether to use the preposition "in" or "for".

Comment: I think you've answered your own question: "...so that we can discuss **for** a period of of five minutes." This is exactly the same use of *for*.

Comment: In ten minutes you should pause for 5 minutes.